# Alternative syntax i can use to find the percentage and round to 2

Tags: mysql, sql, syntax, rounding, percentage

Please can someone help me with an alternative syntax to the code below, this is yielding an error in MySQL specifically the round statement cos without it and the count, the query runs well... Got the syntax from a lesson I'm following.
Here is the question: What percentage of days in 2020 were breakout days vs non-breakout days? Round the percentages to 2 decimal places

```
SELECT
  ticker,
  ROUND(
    SUM(CASE WHEN price > open THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
      / COUNT(*)::NUMERIC,
    2
  ) AS breakout_percentage,
  ROUND(
    SUM(CASE WHEN price < open THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
      / COUNT(*)::NUMERIC,
    2
  ) AS non_breakout_percentage
FROM trading.prices
WHERE market_date >= '2020-01-01' AND market_date <= '2020-12-31'
GROUP BY ticker;
```

Comment: ::NUMERIC is not mysql syntax so the lesson isn't appropriate - what is it supposed to do?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to CAST the numeric value to DECIMAL which is more appropriate for this situtation.

```
SELECT CAST((COUNT(*) /100) AS DECIMAL(12,2));
-- or even
SELECT CONCAT (CAST((COUNT(*) /100) AS DECIMAL(12,2)) , '%');
```